# JavaScript events in Google Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm new coding a Chrome Extensions, so for call a function I use this:

```
getElementsByTagName('body').addEventListener("load", function() {

  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {

     alert(tab.url);

  });

}, false);
```

And it doesn't work. I also tried this:

```
getElementsById('bottom').addEventListener("click", function() {

  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {

     alert(tab.url);

  });

}, false);
```

I don't know if maybe the problem is in the manifest.json, so here it is:

```
{

   //Main

   "name": "Linknote",
   "version": "0.4",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "description": "Store all your links",
   "permissions": [
     "storage",
     "http://ajax.googleapis.com/",
     "tabs"
   ],

//Chrome Tab

   "browser_action": {

     "default_title": "helloworld",      // optional; shown in tooltip
     "default_popup": "popup.html"        // optional

   }

}
```

Comment: Which file is that JavaScript code in?

Comment: The file is named `popup.js`, and I add it to the extension with this `<script src="popup.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using browser action of Chrome, that should actually go this way.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function(tab){
    -- Your javascript code here --
});
```

I suppose this is what you are missing !!

Comment: I think I don't understand. That adds an `click` event to the tab? I want a click event on a button, and that event would get the actual tab url, but I'm not sure if that code would do that, I'm a really beginner with chrome extensions

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code: the first one is that you are forgetting to add the `document` object on your getElementById. Just ran this code in my popup.html and had no problem whatsoever.

```
document.getElementById("bottom").addEventListener("click", function() { 
       console.log("Clicked") 
}, false);
```

The second one is that you are forgetting that getElementsByTagName returns a NodeCollection, so you need to retrieve the first node you want to add an EventListener to

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("load", function() { 
       console.log("Loaded") 
}, false);
```

Your code returns syntax errors in the [Developer Toolbar](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/); in order to open it up in your Chrome Extension, click on your Browse Action Icon / Page Action Icon and Right-click on the Popup. Click on "Inspect Element" will show you a whole new world.

Comment: I have check this code in the Developer Toolbar, and returns this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null", so the element `bottom` isn't found. What could be the problem?

Thank's advance!

Comment: You need an element with the id "bottom" in order to use `getElementById`. If you want an element then you can use `getElementsByTagName` and iterate through the list returned :)

Comment: Yeah, I used it in normal JS scripts, but in my Google Extension it doesn't work! I don't know why :S

Comment: Can you post your popup.html?

Comment: `<html>
<head>
 <title>Extension</title>

   <style>
     
      body {
        min-width:348px;
        max-height: 700px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
      }

   </style>
   <script src="linknote.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<button id='button' type="bottom">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Then it's `document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() { 
       console.log("Clicked") 
}, false);`. I thought you had a footer with a "bottom" id :)

Comment: The Developer Toolbar stills returning `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null` :S

Comment: Can you post your linknote.js?

Comment: `document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("Clicked") }, false);`

Comment: You are trying to get an element it hasn't been loaded in the DOM yet. As a good practice, try to put `<script>` tags after the `<body>` to ensure the body was loaded or use a DOM ready-check code, if you do it here it will work afterwards.

Comment: I can't do the first thing, the console returns `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:"` How I load the button in the DOM in a external script?

Comment: Put the `<script>` tag inside the `<body>` tag but after the `<button>` one. The warning is related about [CSP](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/)